# Use Microsoft DependencyInjection in TopShelf and Quartz scope problem

Tags: dependency-injection, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, topshelf

I use TopShelf and Quartz for scheduling some job as a Windows service. For Dependency Injection I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. My problem is for Scope functionality, I want when configuring a service in scope lifecycle(for instance ISampleService), Per round of running job, Dispose of the scope lifecycle services and for the next round instantiate again, But scope lifecycle behaves like the singleton lifecycle. following is my code:

Dependencies:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Spi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Topshelf;
```

Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var provider = RegisterServices();

    HostFactory.Run(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Service<SampleTask>(s =>
        {
            s.ConstructUsing(() => provider.GetService<SampleTask>());
            s.WhenStarted(async f => await f.Start(provider));
            s.WhenStopped(f => f.Stop());
        });

        cfg.RunAsLocalSystem();
        cfg.SetDescription("description");
        cfg.SetDisplayName("name");
        cfg.SetServiceName("service");
    });
}
```

RegisterServices method

```
public static ServiceProvider RegisterServices()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();

    services.AddTransient<SampleTask>();
    services.AddTransient<IJob, SampleJob>();
    services.AddScoped<ISampleService, SampleService>

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    return provider;
}
```

JobFactory:

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    protected readonly IServiceProvider Container;

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Container.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Task:

```
public class SampleTask
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;

    public SampleTask(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
    {
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    public async Task Start(ServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(provider);

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<IJob>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Sample1", "SampleGroup")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(10)
                .RepeatForever())
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        await scheduler.Start();
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Job:

```
public class SampleJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ISampleService _sampleService;

    public SampleJob(ISampleService sampleService)
    {
        _sampleService = sampleService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @DaImTo yes, I add my solution tomorrow

Comment: @MohammadAkbari a lot of time passed, but maybe you can still post solution?

Comment: @MohammadAkbari what is your solution?

Comment: @AlexTertyshnyk  I have added my solution

Comment: @HeikoScholze I have added my solution

Comment: @DaImTo I added my solution!

Answer (score 3):

I create a WorkerService project and add some required packages in `csproj` file as following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Topshelf" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Topshelf.Extensions.Hosting" Version="0.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

For support transient, scoped and singleton we need to add some classes

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<QuartzJobRunner>();
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        // we let the DI container handler this
    }
}

[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class QuartzJobRunner : IJob
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public QuartzJobRunner(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            if (scope.ServiceProvider
    .GetRequiredService(context.JobDetail.JobType) is IJob job)
                await job.Execute(context);
        }
    }
}

public class QuartzHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
    private readonly IJobFactory _jobFactory;

    public QuartzHostedService(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory,
     IJobFactory jobFactory)
    {
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
        _jobFactory = jobFactory;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(stoppingToken);
        scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;

        var jobDetail = JobBuilder
            .Create<Job1>()
            .WithIdentity("Job1")
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("Trigger1")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(15)
                .RepeatForever())
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger, stoppingToken);

        await scheduler.Start(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Then I create the job that I want to implement my logic

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class Job1 : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<Job1> _logger;
    private readonly Service1 _service1;

    public Job1(ILogger<Job1> logger, Service1 service1)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _service1 = service1;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Service Id: {_service1.Id}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class Service1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Service1()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

The Main class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args);

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            hostBuilder.Build().Run();
        }
        else
        {
            hostBuilder.RunAsTopshelfService(hc =>
            {
                hc.SetDisplayName("Task1");
                hc.SetDescription("Task1");
                hc.SetServiceName("Task1");
            });
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
                services.AddSingleton<QuartzJobRunner>();
                services.AddScoped<Job1>();

                services.AddSingleton<Service1>();
                //services.AddScoped<Service1>();
                //services.AddTransient<Service1>();

                services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();
            });
}
```

After running the project, you can check the log and by checking `Service1 Id` confirm that the solution will work.

Note that in `ConfigureServices`, the following dependency definitions must not change

```
services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<QuartzJobRunner>();
services.AddScoped<Job1>();
```

And by changing the dependency scope of `Service1` class you can see all the dependency level has been supported.